# JQuery $(window).load doesnt fadeOut() my div when other JQuery code to submit form is called

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have this jquery on every page:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   // PAGE IS FULLY LOADED  
   // FADE OUT YOUR OVERLAYING DIV
   $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

which fades out a div when the page is fully loaded.

On all pages i have a form and this Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#message").hide();
        $("#please_wait_box").hide();
        $("#reviewtickets").submit(function(e) {
            $("#message").hide();
            $("#please_wait_box").show();
            e.preventDefault();
            dataString = $("#reviewtickets").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "reviewtickets_go.php",
                cache: false,
                data: dataString,
                success: function(res) {
                    $("#please_wait_box").hide();
                    $("#message").html(res);
                    $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
                    if (res.indexOf("success") != -1) {
                        window.location.href = res.substr(8);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

so it basically calls another page to submit the form without moving away from the page.

When the forms are submitted, the page is called to save the data in the above jquery code but my jquery load function doesnt fade out because it cannot see that the page has fully loaded

how can i stop the loading function if the form submit code is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the div had an id and class both of `overlay`

the jquery needed to be the `class` and not the `id` as the css was on the `class`

Answer (score 0):

call it inside the success callback of ajax . success function callback is called when the ajax request is successfully made and datas are returned from the server.

```
success: function(res){
     $("#please_wait_box").hide();
     $("#message").html(res);
     $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
     $('#overlay').fadeOut(); //<---here
     if (res.indexOf("success") != -1) {
        window.location.href = res.substr(8);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Or better yet, `$(window).load();`

Comment: i have just tried that but its not fading out, i tried using hide() too but still nothing. on each page i am including settings.php which has the #overlay div and the jquery to fade it out on page load. would it make any difference that the div is on the included page?